# How to refer from eclipse to a WebSphere server when the profile itself isn't in the WebSphere folder?

Tags: eclipse, websphere, devenv

I have a two level problem:

I have websphere installed.
I am working with eclipse and I want to configure a new server which refers to a websphere server.

However, I want the profile of the server (along with my server-side application, of course) to be placed in some folder not neccessarily in the websphere folder.

Questions:
1. Do I need any plugins for this?
2. Can all this be done using only eclipse or do I need to envolve WebSphere as well?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The WAS Profiles can be created in any directory. It does not need to be under a WebSphere folder.

This can be done using the WASProfile binaries which should be available under /bin directory (or its sub folders)

HTH
Manglu